# Autocomplete using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking for an auto complete jQuery plug which support both tag (like stackoverflow's) and picture (like facebook's search). Any recommendations?

Comment: you can use jQuery autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/.. and modify as your need

Comment: Using custom data in jQuery autocomplete http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI has [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which is easy to use.

You pass it an array of possible values (either from the server or client side) and the autocomplete takes it from there.

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) is an example that may help show you how to use custom data.

**Excerpt from jQuery UI**

```
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript", "AppleScript",
            "Asp", "BASIC",
            "C", "C++",
            "Clojure", "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion", "Erlang",
            "Fortran", "Groovy",
            "Haskell", "Java",
            "JavaScript", "Lisp",
            "Perl", "PHP",
            "Python", "Ruby",
            "Scala", "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

And the html:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
</div>
```